# How to retrieve data with Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, call

i like to retrieve a string with an Ajax call but i keep getting the whole html page in my response.

What is the way to just retrieve the string?

```
$.ajax({
                    url: '{$domainpath}{$language}/reservations/updatestartdates',
                    data: {property:property,stayduration:stayduration},
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json'
                }).done(function(response){
                    alert(response);
                });

private function updateAvailableStartDates(){
    if(isset($_POST['property']) && !empty($_POST['property']) && isset($_POST['stayduration']) && !empty($_POST['stayduration'])){
        $property = $_POST['property'];
        $stayduration = $_POST['stayduration'];
    }
    //handle code

    echo json_encode('only this string');
}
```

Comment: You need to echo _only_ the string if it's an AJAX request

Comment: @DipeshParmar what's that good for?

Comment: Place your update function before the content of the page gets outputted, and add an `exit;` after the `echo`, that way it exits if the `POST` request matches etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically a good idea to exit right after printing JSON to prevent content (maybe \n) from breaking the response.

```
echo json_encode('only this string');
exit();
```

Comment: This one worked for me indeed! I also had to change my encode like this 'echo json_encode(array('success'=>$string));' and catch it with 'availableDates = response.success.split(',');'

Answer (score 2):

It will retrieve all the output from `url: '{$domainpath}{$language}/reservations/updatestartdates'`,

So if you want string then only `echo` string in your server page(Remove all html output)

Also Change `echo json_encode('only this string');` to `echo json_encode(array('only this string'));`

Answer (score 0):

I think your function send response with layout enabled mode, so that string comes with wrapped layout. May be you need to disable layout in the controller for the calling function
`(url: '{$domainpath{$language}/reservations/updatestartdates')`.